# How can I save information to my database when information is to be saved in different tables?

Tags: c#, sql, database, transactions

I have to save the following variables to a database:

```
        string PoliciaID = Session["username"];
        string PlacaAuto = Page.Request.QueryString["placaauto"];
        string Carnet = Page.Request.QueryString["carnet"];
        string Fecha = DateTime.Now;
        string TipoInfraccion = Page.Request.QueryString["tipo"];
```

PoliciaID is the primary key of another table called **Policia** and Carnet is primary key of a table called **Persona**.

How could I save information in this situation using C#?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two INSERT or UPDATE commands, one per table, executed as a single unit of work in a transaction context.  Either both should succeed or both should fail and rollback.

[This](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/transactions.html) might help you learn about transactions.

Comment: Can you give me a clear example of what a transaction context is? I've Binged it and found what it theoretically is - but I don't know how to apply that in code. Again, thanks for your help brother! :D

Comment: @Sergio - see my comment below. (I wanted to preserve the formatting so didn't just put in a comment here)

Answer (score 1):

As @duffymo said

```
DECLARE @FirstTab TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
DECLARE @SecondTab TABLE (Col3 INT, Col4 INT)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO @FirstTab ( Col1, Col2 ) VALUES ( 1,2 )
    INSERT INTO @SecondTab ( Col3, Col4 ) VALUES ( 3,4 )
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

(you'll probably also want to add in some mechanism to communicate to the caller whether it succeeded (and committed the changes) or failed (rolled back) )

So the idea here is that the two inserts will *both* happen, or neither. If there's an exception thrown along the way, it'll jump into the `catch` block to roll back anything that's already been done. But normally it'll just do the two INSERTS, commit the work, and continue on its way.